# Magento call block for specific product in list.phtml

Tags: magento, php

I want to print some additional data for each product on list.phtml that will depend on the product. For example, print html with New and Sale labels for each product (this is just an example). I want to somehow separate logic from .phtml file and remain in phtml just a call for it. What is the best way to achieve it? Also I want to minimize overriding core files and make it more independent.
My ideas are:

1. Create my own block, create and call it in .phtml and pass there my
   product with setData:

   ```
   $this->getLayout()->createBlock("namespace/block")->
   setTemplate("path/to/template")->setData('product', $_product)
   ```

   and then call getProduct() inside my block .php file. But for some reasons that doesn't work.
2. The best-looking solution for me, but not sure if it's allowed. Create new block in layout files and call it with `getChildHtml('block_name')`. But I don't know how to pass there current product or how to make it to be able to access through $this inside my .php file.
3. Override product block and add my own methods like getRibbons(). The worst solution for me because this will requre html writing in .php block and will override core block.

I'm pretty new to magento, maybe I am missing some basic concepts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Extend your Product Block PHP and add new methods you want in it. Then in your `module.xml` where you are referencing core Product Block, replace it with your newly created Block.

Now, from PHTML files you can easily call the PHP block's methods using `$this`

Comment: If he's creating a new module, he might as well specify a new layout file for his module, especially since he mentioned wanting to keep this outside of core.

Comment: There is no reference to product block, there is one to catalog/product_list instead. So when I extend it and use my own block no one will be able to reference old catalog/product_list block, right?

Comment: @nevermourn NO. By extending you are increasing it's functionality. Your new product_list will refer with the functionality of old catalog/product_list as well. FYI, By product block, i meant catalog/product_list.

Comment: Oh, thanks, finally I got it. I just have to use the same "name" attribute in my layout as in catalog.xml.